# Capistrano - cannot find ruby

Tags: rbenv, capistrano3

Its confusing. I've gone through the documentation, I know capistrano uses a non-login, non-interactive shell.

So I have this simple task

```
desc 'Echo environment vars'
namespace :env do
  task :echo do
    on roles(:app) do
      execute 'echo $PATH'
      execute 'printenv'
      execute 'echo $PATH'
      execute '/usr/bin/env ruby --version'
    end
  end
end
```

Run cap production env:echo

The output is this

```
DEBUG[558ffc94] Running /usr/bin/env [ ! -d ~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5 ] on mycompany.com
DEBUG[558ffc94] Command: [ ! -d ~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5 ]
DEBUG[558ffc94] Finished in 7.972 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
INFO[c9043b5c] Running /usr/bin/env echo $PATH on mycompany.com
DEBUG[c9043b5c] Command: echo $PATH
INFO[c9043b5c] Finished in 0.211 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG[c9043b5c]         /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
INFO[c9043b5c] Finished in 0.211 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO[7a765d1d] Running /usr/bin/env printenv on mycompany.com
DEBUG[7a765d1d] Command: ( PATH=$HOME/.rbenv/shims:$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.1.5 /usr/bin/env printenv )
DEBUG[7a765d1d]         RBENV_VERSION=2.1.5
DEBUG[7a765d1d]         RBENV_ROOT=/home/deployer/.rbenv
DEBUG[7a765d1d]         PATH=/home/deployer/.rbenv/shims:/home/deployer/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
DEBUG[7a765d1d]         XDG_SESSION_ID=159
DEBUG[7a765d1d]         TERM=xterm
DEBUG[7a765d1d] 
DEBUG[7a765d1d]         SHELL=/bin/bash
DEBUG[7a765d1d]         SSH_CLIENT=172.16.10.10 51174 22
DEBUG[7a765d1d]         SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/3
DEBUG[7a765d1d]         USER=deployer
DEBUG[7a765d1d] 
DEBUG[7a765d1d]         SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-OtFWklQB4e/agent.7579
DEBUG[7a765d1d]         MAIL=/var/mail/deployer
DEBUG[7a765d1d]         PWD=/home/deployer
DEBUG[7a765d1d]         LANG=en_US.UTF-8
DEBUG[7a765d1d]         SHLVL=1
DEBUG[7a765d1d]         HOME=/home/deployer
DEBUG[7a765d1d]         LOGNAME=deployer
DEBUG[7a765d1d]         SSH_CONNECTION=172.16.10.10 51174 172.16.10.55
DEBUG[7a765d1d]         LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
DEBUG[7a765d1d]         XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1001
DEBUG[7a765d1d]         _=/usr/bin/env
INFO[7a765d1d] Finished in 0.228 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO[461230a4] Running /usr/bin/env echo $PATH on mycompany.com
DEBUG[461230a4] Command: echo $PATH
INFO[461230a4] Finished in 0.209 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG[461230a4]         /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
INFO[461230a4] Finished in 0.209 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO[0d327934] Running /usr/bin/env /usr/bin/env ruby --version on mycompany.com
DEBUG[0d327934] Command: /usr/bin/env ruby --version
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host mycompany.com: /usr/bin/env ruby --version exit status: 127
/usr/bin/env ruby --version stdout: Nothing written
/usr/bin/env ruby --version stderr: Nothing written
config/deploy.rb:253:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
SSHKit::Command::Failed: /usr/bin/env ruby --version exit status: 127
/usr/bin/env ruby --version stdout: Nothing written
/usr/bin/env ruby --version stderr: Nothing written
config/deploy.rb:253:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => env:echo
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I notice that printenv shows a different PATH and echoing $PATH shows something different. Why?

Next, why is "/usr/bin/env ruby --version" failing?

I try replacing "execute '/usr/bin/env ruby --version'" with "execute 'which ruby'", I get "SSHKit::Command::Failed: which ruby exit status: 1"

I give it the whole path - "execute '/usr/bin/which ruby'", same result - "SSHKit::Command::Failed: /usr/bin/which ruby exit status: 1"

What is going on? Why isn't the PATH shown with "printenv" being picked up?

Thanks for helping clarify.

Answer (score 0):

This is nicely explained in the [sshkit gem command map section](https://github.com/capistrano/sshkit#the-command-map):

> It's often a problem that programmatic SSH sessions don't have the same environment variables as interactive sessions.
>
> A problem often arises when calling out to executables expected to be on the $PATH. Under conditions without dotfiles or other environmental configuration, $PATH may not be set as expected, and thus executables are not found where expected.

Btw. just to make clear - capistrano uses sshkit as its backend.

As for the high-level approach to capistrano, I'd recommend just using [capistrano-rbenv](https://github.com/capistrano/rbenv) + [capistrano-rbenv-install](https://github.com/capistrano-plugins/capistrano-rbenv-install) gems (disclaimer, I wrote the latter one).

With these 2 gems, all you need is to have ruby version specified, for example:

```
# in config/deploy.rb
set :rbenv_ruby, '2.0.0-p247'
```

And **everything** else should just work smoothly! Even the exact ruby version will be installed to the server if necessary, so that the user doesn't have to fiddle with it.

Comment: Thanks! But in the above case, the printenv line is showing the PATH and the printenv line is executed through capistrano. Therein lies a bit of the confusion. If the bashrc is not sourced, then fine, but then printenv shouldn't be showing the path that has rbenv on it right? But in this case, printenv shows rbenv on the path but echo $PATH does not. Both executed by capistrano.